# CNN - Detecting Handwritten Smilies: ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (26,26,3) into shape (26)

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

In my root folder *`images`* I have three folders called *`0`*, *`1`*, *`2`*. In folder *`0`* there are `no smilies`. In folder *`1`* there are `happy handwritten smilies` and in folder *`2`* there are `sad handwritten smilies`.
The images are *`jpg`* color images with the dimension *`26x26`*.

This is my code

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, Flatten
import numpy as np
import os
import cv2
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

def getImages(path, classes):
    folder = os.listdir(path)
    classes_counter = 0
    images = []
    images_classes = []

    for x in range (0,len(folder)):
        myPicList = os.listdir(path+"/"+ str(classes[classes_counter]))
        for pic in myPicList:
            img_path = path+"/" + str(classes[classes_counter]) + "/" + pic
            img = cv2.imread(img_path)
            img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            images.append(img)
            images_classes.append(classes_counter)
        classes_counter +=1

    images = np.array(images, dtype="float") / 255
    return images, images_classes

def createModel(classes, images_dimension):
    classes_amount = len(np.unique(classes))
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=images_dimension))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))

    model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))

    model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(classes_amount, activation='softmax'))

    return model


labels = [0,1,2]
images, images_classes = getImages('training-images', labels)
images_dimension=(26,26,3)

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(images, images_classes, test_size=0.2)  # if 1000 images split will 200 for testing
X_train, X_validation, Y_train, Y_validation = train_test_split(X_train, Y_train, test_size=0.2) # if 1000 images 20% of remaining 800 will be 160 for validation

model = createModel(labels, images_dimension)
batch_size = 20
epochs = 100
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_validation, Y_validation))
model.evaluate(X_test,Y_test,verbose=0)
```

In the Line `images = np.array(images, dtype="float") / 255` I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train-nn.py", line 54, in <module>
    images, images_classes = getImages('training-images', labels)
  File "train-nn.py", line 24, in getImages
    images = np.array(images, dtype="float") / 255
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (26,26) into shape (26)
```

I think something is wrong with the datastructure or with the array structure. I have no clue what I did wrong. Maybe someone known this problem and can give me a hint!

Here you can download the whole project as zip file.
http://fileshare.mynotiz.de/cnn-handwritten-smilies.zip

Comment: it will be good to keep the project link for reference active(zip file), if any one come across this situation it will be helpful for them. it is good and simple example also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. One of my test-data images was not in the format of 26x26 it was 26x23.